# Amateur en linux

Tags: linux

Soy nuevo en el tema de Linux y quiero usar una máquina virtual para empezar a aprender el OS Linux.

¿Qué máquina virtual y que versión o modelo de Linux (no tengo claro cómo son las versiones o parches) debería descargarme, si adjuntan los links seria un gran detalle.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, infortunadamente esta pregunta se basa en opiniones y no se ajusta al formato de StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear máquinas virtuales puedes usar [`VM Virtualbox`](https://www.virtualbox.org/), el cual es gratuito.

Para la versión de Linux, como no especificas que tipo de Linux quieres, puedes empezar con [`Ubuntu`](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) el cual tiene interfaz gráfica.

Answer (score 0):

Como máquina virtual yo utilizo VirtualBox. Para empezar puedes comenzar a usar Ubuntu ya que suele ser lo más fácil para iniciarse.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estás en *Windows*. Entonces, como dicen los demás. Bajate *VirtualBox* y luego instalalo. Existen varios sabores de GNU Linux. Una buena distro amigable es Ubuntu. Bajate la última versión, que es la *"16.10"*.